# Accessing user photos with Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm fairly new to iOS development and I have an app that already enables a user to login with Facebook. My question has two parts...

1) I don't necessarily want to ask for the "user_photos" permission upon login/signup, just when the user goes into their "edit profile" page and wants to grab some of their Facebook photos for their profile. How can I request additional permissions, beyond the ones I requested upon signup later in my app?

2) I also would like to know how to access a user's photos using the Facebook Graph API. I'd like that modal view from Facebook to appear that presents a user with all their albums and photos. I see a lot of documentation on the Facebook developer site about accessing a user's profile picture (I've already done this) and accessing specific photos, but, in this case, I don't know what specific photo I want. I want the user to select one of their photos, and certainly don't want to request ALL their photos. Does anyone know how to format a FB request so I can get that Facebook view to appear that allows a user to pick from all their photos?

Thanks,